# qml button not firing, same with MouseArea

Tags: button, qml, applicationwindow, mousearea

Ive created a new QML project based on Qt 5.9.3.  I setup a simple ApplicationWindow with a Button as well as my own button (MyButton) and I never get the onClicked() event to fire (apparently) for either of them.  My application window pops up with 2 buttons showing.  Clicking on either of them shows nothing in my console output.

Im also pre-compiling my qml source files in the .pro file if that even matters.  I get some Font errors on startup which I fix in the C++ to
get some fonts going so I can see something, other than that there are no
errors or warnings.  Ive spent a couple hours just trying to get a simple
mouse click event through with no luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Here's my main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: "App Title"
    color: "white"

    Button {
        text: "Button"
        onClicked: {
            console.log("clicked")
        }
    }
    MyButton {
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.top: parent.top
        onClicked: {
            console.log("my button clicked")
        }
    }
}
```

and MyButton.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7

Rectangle {
    id: button
    width: 100
    height: 50
    color: "yellow"

    signal clicked()

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: button
        visible: false
        enabled: true
        onClicked: {
            console.log("my button mouse clicked")
            clicked()
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:  I did a very stupid thing.  in my main.cpp file which I did
not include I thought I would be cleaner and move my QQmlEngine init code
into its own separate method.  Of course when the engine reference went
out of scope it caused my issue.  I didn't look there because I wrongly assumed that the qml code wouldn't work at all if something were wrong there. Sorry to get back on this so late, its been a very busy week and sorry for wasting bandwidth.  Thank you for the great debugging suggestions as well for future reference!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about your problem with the `Button` from QtQuick.Controls 2.0 - it works perfectly for me.

With your own implementation of the `MyButton`, that does not work for me either.

The reason is that `visible: false` will deactivate the `MouseArea` (and all the children of it) - setting `enabled: true` won't change that.
Setting `visible: false` is unnecessary anyway, as a `MouseArea` has nothing to render - being effictively invisible.

Once you have changed that, you should get a warning:

> `Error: Insufficient arguments`

as you call the signal `clicked` of the `MouseArea` which requires an argument (`MouseEvent`). To call your self-defined signal, call `button.clicked()` instead.R

---

If you still don't get anyting, you will need to take further debugging steps.

1. Check whether you can generate any output using `console.log` for example by adding `Component.onComplete: console.log("Output works")` to one of your objects.
2. Check whether your input is really broken, by changing the color of the `Rectangle` when the `MouseArea` is clicked: `color: (mouseArea.pressed ? 'red' : 'green')`
3. Install an `eventFilter` to your `QGuiApplication` (in C++) that will print something, if an `MouseEvent` is registered.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, that a MouseArea gets completely deactivated if is parent item is set visible=false. After setting the parent item to visible=true again, the MouseArea is not activated automatically. It has to be set visible=true too.